# Set only specific dates in datepicker android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am building an appointment booker app and i want to have the user select the date/time of the booking from a date picker. The part I'm having a problem with is excluding certain date/times from the selectable list.

For example a user selecting a booking would not be able to see before 9am and after 6pm on a day, Sundays and as 11am and 2 pm are already booked (for the sake of an example) they should  not be visible as well.

Comment: That seems to be more about removing the year selector from the date picker completely? I still would like all 3 fields just with certain dates omitted based on the data im pulling in.

Comment: Этот ответ может быть полезен [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68149528/16067747](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68149528/16067747)