# Block Fridays from DatePicker

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a project with `DatePicker`. I'm already using `setMinDate` and `setMaxDate`, and now I want to block all Fridays.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DatePicker date = findViewById(R.id.datePicker4);
    date.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,13);
    date.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

    date.init(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,clock.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: your title says to block Saturday, but your text says to block Friday.

Comment: try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599203/disable-specific-dates-of-day-in-android-date-picker