# How to disable all friday and previous date from tommorrow in android Date Picker?

Tags: java, android

I want to disable all previous date from tomorrow and all Friday in android Date picker but i was able to do able to disable the previous date from tomorrow.

Heres my Code.

```
 Calendar tomorrowdate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    tomorrowdate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
                    new DatePickerDialog(mActivity, indate, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );
                    datePickerDialog.show();
```

i need to disable previous date from tomorrow as well as all the friday at once. Any Solution.

Comment: You can not disable particular dated in default `DatePickerDialog` . You have to use a Custom date Picker . Probably a third party library Just search for it .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable specific dates of day in Android date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599203/disable-specific-dates-of-day-in-android-date-picker)